Digital signature to PDF file - pkcs11.dll not detected from the system
I want to sign a PDF file using a digital signature from a USB token (containing the private and public keys). When I try to achieve this using PKCS11.dll, the system detects an error and throws a 'module could not be found' error.
C:\Windows\System32\pkcs11.dll
Error loading PKCS#11 library: Cannot open library at C:\Windows\System32\pkcs11.dll: The specified module could not be found.

My Code:
import os
import pkcs11

# Path to the PKCS#11 library (update this path accordingly)
pkcs11_lib_path = r'C:\Windows\System32\pkcs11.dll'  # or SysWOW64 for 32-bit
print(pkcs11_lib_path)
# Initialize the PKCS#11 library
try:
    lib = pkcs11.lib(pkcs11_lib_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error loading PKCS#11 library: {e}")
    exit(1)

I tried my code block above mentioned

The answer is in the error message The specified module could not be found
You must supply a full path for your token's PKCS#11 module provided by your hardware manufacturer.
The library located in system32 / SysWOW64don't need to supply path to them. Module name is enough.
Based on my experience there are no token manufacturers that call they library simply as a pkcs11.dll.
rtPKCS11.dll, eTPKCS11.dll or etc is the more realistic names.
